# Flutter 2.0 Firestore: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the below code to get data from firestore.

```
      return ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
            print(doc.data());
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(doc.data()["description"]),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
```

But I got the error below:

Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  title: Text(doc.data()["description"]),

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data()` function now returns `Object?` which means you have to cast it to a `Map<String, dynamic>` now.

```dart
      return ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
            final data = doc.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            print(data);
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(data["description"]),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 return ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
          Map allData = doc.data();
           // print(doc.data());
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(allData["description"]),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
```